# cannot find undefined function array_except() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

Upgrading an old application I inherited I run in quite some trouble.

Being new in php frameworks I am learning a lot..
Now, upgrading form laravel 5.8 to 6 I got the error:

"Call to undefined function array_except() " with reference to login/register.blade.php

I cannot find the "array_except()" anywhere in my whole application.

can someone help me and explain how I can solve this (and similar problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function seems to be replaced from version 5.7 with `Arr::except`

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-except